# Remove unused styles from wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to [dequeue](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dequeue_style/)/[deregister](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_script/) styles that are unneccesarry(WooCommerce,Contact form 7) from all post/pages of my wordpress website.

Tried [offical](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/) WooCommerce's way to disable these extra styles and scripts, but it's not dequeue-ing those since styles are still loaded in the source code and Google PageSpeed Insights is still showing them as being rendered; so:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', 'jk_dequeue_styles' );
function jk_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-general'] );    // Remove the gloss
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-layout'] );     // Remove the layout
    unset( $enqueue_styles['woocommerce-smallscreen'] );    // Remove the smallscreen optimisation
    return $enqueue_styles;
}

// Or just remove them all in one line
add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_false' );
```

in `functions.php` Isn't working. I also tried to remove them like this:

```
function remove_assets() {
    wp_dequeue_style('wc-block-vendors-style-css');
    wp_deregister_style('wc-block-vendors-style-css');
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'remove_assets', PHP_INT_MAX );
```

Pointing at specific style id `wc-block-vendors-style-css` and setting `PHP_INT_MAX`.
It's still not removing that specific style.

[image]

**Notes:**

This `functions.php` belongs to the child theme of a custom, redone twenty-twenty WordPress theme and cache has been cleared. I've tried most of the answers here from the StackOverflow of users' having similar issues, but not a single one worked.

Woocommerce support is enabled in the theme.

How to dequeue/deregister styles and scripts with WordPress 5.6 in 2021?

Comment: In addition to the answer provided... Your Official answer uses the incorrect function. https://gist.github.com/woogists/8af93b901eac5d4dc2fb1452516c1079#file-wc-disable-default-stylesheet-php

Comment: @HowardE That snippet is part of the woocomerce docs source I put in question, tried that one as well, not working. All WooCommerce styles and scripts are still loaded

Comment: The gist says `add_filter( 'woocommerce_enqueue_styles', '__return_empty_array' );` what you put above is `__return_false`

Comment: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/disable-the-default-stylesheet/#section-1 read this; your suggestion is in there, tried it, it's not working..

Comment: In this case, you should ensure that your functions are actually running.  You can try dumping to error_log something to validate your functions are triggering.

Comment: @Ognj3n I tested your code with my Woocommerce install, and it dequeues the styles correctly. I guess it is not related to the code snippet. Please check if you are changing the correct file. I guess the child theme is not activated, or you might work on a different codebase. If the problem persists, you can DM me so that I can help you in more detail. You can find my contact detail on my profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that in order to remove those styles the Woocomerce integration in the active theme was required.

```
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

According to @Aliakseyenka Ihar - I've tested myself,
When I added `deregister` before `wp_dequeue_style` - it removes the vendor-style

```
function remove_assets() {
    wp_deregister_style('wc-block-vendors-style');
    wp_dequeue_style('wc-block-vendors-style');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_assets', 11);
```

Or ninja way

```
add_filter( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jk_dequeue_styles', 99999 );
function jk_dequeue_styles( $enqueue_styles ) {
    global $wp_styles;
    unset ( $wp_styles->registered['wc-block-vendors-style'] );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your stylesheet is registered and enqueued correctly then...

```
function dequeue_css() {
    wp_dequeue_style('wc-block-vendors-style');
    wp_deregister_style('wc-block-vendors-style');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_css');
// add a priority if you need it
// add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','dequeue_css',100);
```

Or you can try this way:

```
add_filter('style_loader_src', function($href){
    if(strpos($href, "wc-block-vendors-style") !== false) {
        return false;
    }
    return $href;
});
```